# if condition in concurrency in GHA

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to add IF condition in concurrency in github action?

I want to do following but only when branch name is not `master`

```
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

Trigger on my yaml file is as follows:

```
name: Build
on:
  push:
```

This triggers on push on any branch (master or feature)

Comment: You can't use the if expression with [concurrency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency), but you can use expression with the concurrency `group` subtype. For example something like: `group: ${{ github.ref && github.ref != 'refs/heads/main' }}`. Did you try it?

Comment: This will stop all workflows irrespective of branch names as long as branch is not `main`. So if feature1 branch has workflow in progress and we push a commit to feature2 branch, this kills feature1 branch workflow

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be an option to use an expression with `refs/heads/feature*` as well?

Answer (score 4):

After trying to achieve this for countless hours, the only thing that worked for me and for our organization was not to tweak `cancel-in-progress`, but rather to make sure every job on `master` has a unique group identifier.

As I've explained [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117321/if-condition-in-concurrency-in-gha#comment133048267_74610814), even when you set `cancel-in-progress` to `false` that only means that there will be **one** job pending at all times. Push three commits in a row and the middle one will be cancelled with `Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for 'refs/heads/master' exists`. Hence, your master branch will look busted even though the test didn't even run. I hope GitHub implements a native support for this.

In meantime, this should work for anyone:

```yaml
# we tend to reserve push only for a master branch to avoid duplicated runs in PRS
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.head_ref && github.ref || github.run_id }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

The second part of the `group` string is an expression known as a [fake ternary](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26738#discussioncomment-3253176).

If we imagine that we have two workflows named "Foo" and "Bar" and we push two commits in a row, this is what we'd get for `group`:

1. on master:

- comit A

  - `Foo-4135785169`
  - `Bar-4135785170`
- commit B

  - `Foo-4135785171`
  - `Bar-4135785172`

2. in a PR:

- commit A:

  - `Foo-refs/pull/14/merge`
  - `Bar-refs/pull/14/merge`
- commit B:

  - `Foo-refs/pull/14/merge`
  - `Bar-refs/pull/14/merge`

(obviously, IDs will be different for your scenario)

---

tl;dr

`master`

- Since every single `group` identifier on `master` is always unique (due to the `github.run_id`), a `cancel-in-progress: true` doesn't really affect it.

PRs

- Workflow name in combination with a branch ref (or you can even use a branch name) ensures that the same workflow gets cancelled only within that one branch.
- Two developers can push at the same time in their own PRs and the same workflow will run for both of them.
- One developer pushing multiple times in their own PR will always have only the latest commit running in CI. All previous ones will be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the concurrency group name as-is and simply cancel in-progress tasks *only* if their branch name is something other than `master`:

```yaml
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: ${{ github.ref_name != 'master' }}
```

To learn more about:

- ... operators like `!=`, see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators
- ... literals (e.g. returning `true` or `false` from an expression), see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#literals
- ... what values you can access on the `github` object, see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-contents-of-the-github-context

Comment: I was so happy when I first saw this, but it doesn't work for all cases. Unfortunately, if you push three commits in a row (commit A,B and C), the second one will be cancelled. The documentation could be a bit more straight-forward. It says: ["Any previously pending job or workflow in the concurrency group will be canceled"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency). It's not possible to have multiple pending jobs. In that case `master` branch will show red X - a failing job for a commit B :(.